# JSON: Trouble editing a JSON file in Python

Tags: python, arrays, json, dictionary

What I want to do is remove the array containing "Nike" under the "Shoe" variable.
Here is the Json file:

```
{
    "Shoes/Colorways":
    [
        {
            "Shoe": "Nike",
            "Colorway": "Blue"
        },
        {
            "Shoe": "Jordan",
            "Colorway": "Blue"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want the end result of the Json file to look like this:

```
{
    "Shoes/Colorways":
    [
        {
            "Shoe": "Jordan",
            "Colorway": "Blue"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is the code I used to try to remove the array with "Nike":

```
import json

path = 'keywords.json'

with open(path, 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

for info in data['Shoes/Colorways']:
    if info['Shoe'] == 'Nike':
        data.remove(info['Shoe'])
        data.remove(info['Colorway'])
    else:
        pass
print(data)
```

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\TestUser\Desktop\Projects\Programs\json.py", line 10, in <module>
    data.remove(info['Shoe'])
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'remove'
```

I realized that `.remove` is only for lists and I cannot seem to find out how to do what I need to do in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import json

path = 'keywords.json'

with open(path, 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

data['Shoes/Colorways'] = [info for info in data['Shoes/Colorways'] if info['Shoe'] != 'Nike']

print(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove operation doesn't exist in the dictionary. Better to skip some value that is not necessary.

```
 print([info for info in data['Shoes/Colorways'] if info['Shoe'] != 'Nike'])
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you, `.remove` does not exist on a dict object. Notice carefully that `data` is a dict. You should be calling `.remove` on the list -  `data['Shoes/Colorways']` is the list you need to remove from.

It would, however, be far better to simply use a list comprehension that filters out the element instead

```py
data['Shoes/ColorWays'] = [x for x in data['Shoes/ColorWays'] if x['Shoe'] != 'Nike']
```